# jQuery select all data from selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table. I want to get name, lastname, email from all selected rows (check is set). Maybe name, lastname, email will be arrays. 
How can I do it? 
I've tried this:

```js
var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var result = [];
    $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
        result.push($(this).parent().next().text());
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="1" border="2">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Check</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Email</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_1">Petya</td>
    <td id="last_1">L1</td>
    <td id="country_1">Country1</td>
    <td id="email_1">Email1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check_2" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_2">Kolya</td>
    <td id="last_2">L2</td>
    <td id="country_2">Country2</td>
    <td id="email_2">Email2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_3" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_3">Vasya</td>
    <td id="last_3">L3</td>
    <td id="country_3">Country3</td>
    <td id="email_3">Email3</td>
</tr>
```

But I get only selected names. How can I get the other columns?

Comment: i think it has to be `tableControl.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(...)` or not? and why do you use vanilla js for get element by id and not jquery? `$('#myTable')` and not `document.getElementById('myTable'')`

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible way of doing things . I set a class for every type of column. You can use that to find out all the other information of the checked rows.

Observe the console. you get all the information in one object which you can then use for whatever further functions you might want it to do

```js
var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var result = [];
        $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {
            var obj={};
            var parent=$(this).parent().parent();
            obj.name=(parent.find( ".name" ).text());
            obj.last=(parent.find( ".last" ).text());
            obj.country=(parent.find( ".country" ).text());
            obj.email=(parent.find( ".email" ).text());
            result.push(obj);
        });
        console.log(result);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="1" border="2">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Check</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Email</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td class="name" id="name_1">Petya</td>
    <td class="last" id="last_1">L1</td>
    <td class="country" id="country_1">Country1</td>
    <td class="email" id="email_1">Email1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check_2" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td class="name" id="name_2">Kolya</td>
    <td class="last" id="last_2">L2</td>
    <td class="country" id="country_2">Country2</td>
    <td class="email" id="email_2">Email2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_3" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td class="name" id="name_3">Vasya</td>
    <td class="last" id="last_3">L3</td>
    <td class="country" id="country_3">Country3</td>
    <td class="email" id="email_3">Email3</td>
</tr>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @RachelGallen . I really appreciate it. :) Although, I wasnt using jquery and was using plain javascript. But very helpful fiddle. I'm going to save this link.

Comment: @IhavCoder oh yeah, i didn't think of that (the jquery/plain js thing) .. jquery is quite easy and useful though once you get used to it (and it doesn't take long to learn) .. Glad to be of help :)

Comment: @IhavCoder i just saw from your profile that you're already working with jquery.  Didn't notice that before last comment! But sure, help along the way is always good i find.. :)

Comment: Yes, I do work with jquery. I agree, jquery is powerful but this particular task I'm working on required only javascript to be used. Thanks Rachel. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking a button every time you want to sum up your results, i would suggest you handle the **result** object anytime a checkbox is clicked, this makes for a more stable state and handles dynamic changes better. Consider changing your code to look like:

```
var tableControl = $('#mytable');

//An object that maps checkbox id to an object containing name, last and email
var result = {}; 
tableControl.find('input:checkbox').click(function() {
   var key = $(this).attr('id');
   //If checkbox clicked and not checked, then remove object from map
   if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
      delete result[key];
      return;
   }
   var row = $(this).parent().parent();
   //Get children based on the start of the id string
   var firstName = row.children("td[id^='name']").text();
   var lastName = row.children("td[id^='last']").text();
   var email = row.children("td[id^='email']").text();
   result[key] = {
    name: firstName,
    last : lastName,
    email: email
   }
 });
```

This way, anytime a checkbox is clicked, the results object will update immediately to reflect the desired value. The result object would look something like this:

```
{
  "check_1": {
    "name": "Petya",
    "last": "L1",
    "email": "Email1"
  },
  "check_2": {
    "name": "Kolya",
    "last": "L2",
    "email": "Email2"
  },
  "check_3": {
    "name": "Vasya",
    "last": "L3",
    "email": "Email3"
  }
}
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/p35kz2u1/6/**

Comment: I was gonna tell the same thing as you did. I do the same way as you've written here. :D

Comment: Right? I always find it makes more sense (and easier to maintain) to update the dependent values as the event occurs rather than at an arbitrary time when user is ready to use the data.

Comment: Correct. That's why I also do this the same way you've done it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tableControl= document.getElementById('mytable');
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        var result = [];

        $('input:checkbox:checked', tableControl).each(function() {           
            // Get the entire text
            //alert($(this).closest('tr').children('td').text());
            //alert($(this).parent().next().find('td').text());
            // Get each column
            $(this).closest('tr').children('td').each(function(e){
              alert($(this).text());
            });
            result.push($(this).closest('tr').children('td').text());
        });
        alert(result);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="1" border="2">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Check</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Email</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_1">Petya</td>
    <td id="last_1">L1</td>
    <td id="country_1">Country1</td>
    <td id="email_1">Email1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check_2" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_2">Kolya</td>
    <td id="last_2">L2</td>
    <td id="country_2">Country2</td>
    <td id="email_2">Email2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_3" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_3">Vasya</td>
    <td id="last_3">L3</td>
    <td id="country_3">Country3</td>
    <td id="email_3">Email3</td>
</tr>
<button id="btn">Get Data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tableControl= $('#mytable');
$("#btn").click(function () {
    var result = [];
    tableControl('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
        var nodeArray = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');
        var innerArray = [];
        for(var i = 1; i < nodeArray.length; i++) {
            if(nodeArray.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                innerArray.push(nodeArray[i].text());
            }
        }
        if(innerArray.length > 0) {
          result.push(innerArray);
        }
    });
    alert(result);
});
```

please try out this, i have not tested, but i think it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below. I modified your inner query to go to parent and looks for siblings.

```js
 var tableControl = $('#mytable');
 $("#btn").click(function() {

   var result = [];
   $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(item) {
     $(this).parent().siblings().each(function() {      
       result.push($(this).text())
     });
   });
  alert(result)
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="1" border="2">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Check</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Lastname</td>
    <td>Country</td>
    <td>Email</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_1" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_1">Petya</td>
    <td id="last_1">L1</td>
    <td id="country_1">Country1</td>
    <td id="email_1">Email1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input id="check_2" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_2">Kolya</td>
    <td id="last_2">L2</td>
    <td id="country_2">Country2</td>
    <td id="email_2">Email2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="check_3" type="checkbox" name="check[]"></td>
    <td id="name_3">Vasya</td>
    <td id="last_3">L3</td>
    <td id="country_3">Country3</td>
    <td id="email_3">Email3</td>
</tr>
</table>
  <button id ="btn">Click Me</button>
```